# Android app email recipient option not functioning

Tags: java, android

I am using the following example to try to send an email to a specific recipient.

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html#Email

The email client pops up but To: field is empty...any thoughts?

According to the documentation in the above webpage i have mentioned EXTRA_EMAIL fills the recipient email address

**Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL
A string array of all "To" recipient email addresses.**

Here is the code

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
                intent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:")); // only email apps should handle this
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, "testemail@gmail.com");
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Title of the email");
                if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To address should be a String Array:

```
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] { "me@somewhere.com" });
```

Comment: Thanks. I just realized it after seeing your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Note that `ACTION_SENDTO` itself is [not documented to support `EXTRA_EMAIL` or `EXTRA_SUBJECT`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#ACTION_SENDTO). IMHO, the safer approach is to use `mailto:` properly:

```
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:testemail@gmail.com"));
```

Answer (score 0):

As its stated in the document and other answer the address should be array. This the Helper class I am using for composing e-mail

```
public class EmailComposer {

    private Activity activity;
    private String subject;
    private String[] addresses;

    public EmailComposer(Activity activity, String subject, String[] addresses) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.subject = subject;
        this.addresses = addresses;

    }

    public void composeEmail() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:")); // only email apps should handle this
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, addresses);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
        if(activity!=null) {
            if (intent.resolveActivity(activity.getPackageManager()) != null) {
                activity.startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    }
}
```